# Unable to edit existing contributions after CiviCRM upgrade

Tags: civicontribute

Issue arises after upgrading from 5.25 to 5.34.

When attempting to edit any contribution and consequently saving, the form returns an error 'please enter a valid amount'

It appears that the system is auto placing a "CA$" acronym before the numerical value (amount). Unfortunatley, the field isn't editable, therefore prohibiting the opporunity of removing the offending acronym to enable form saving.

I've tried to adjust settings in *Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Locations* to no avail.

Does anyone know how I may fix the issue?

Wordpress: 5.6.4

[image]

Comment: I see a (possibly) related discussion at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-financial

Comment: Yeah it seems similar to the other currency symbol problem. You could try this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19680/files.

Comment: Awesome. That patch worked swimmingl! Thanks to you both

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a couple of members, there is a patch in circulation to define decimals in place of the currency symbol that's causing the problem.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19680/files